# Map with const and non-const values

Tags: c++, templates, constants, stdmap

I'm currently looking at some code that uses instances of both of the following types of maps:

```
std::map<std::string, const Foo>;
std::map<std::string, Foo>;
```

where the implementation of `Foo` is not relevant. As a result, all of the functions that take as input an instance of either of these two have two implementations of them: one for the const `Foo` version and the other for the non-const `Foo` version.

My question is this: is it possible to create something (like a class derived from `std::map`, for example) using templates that will allow me to essentially encapsulate both versions of the types above as one?

Edit: I know I can probably use SFINAE to only have to write one version of each of the relevant functions, but I'm wondering if there's a way to implement something a little bit further "upstream."

I apologize if my question doesn't make sense - I'm not exactly sure how to word it in a nice way.

Comment: What would the return type of a lookup in the map be?  You would have to have a get(K) and a get_const(K) and then have a failure mode when you call get(K) on a key with a const value.   If that's what you want, you could make a map that has a value type of std::variant<T, const T>...but what you're asking to do isn't often a good approach

Comment: Looking at the code... it looks like it's just determined by what kind of map was passed into the function, i.e. if one passed in the const Foo version, then the return type would be a `const Foo&`, and it would be `Foo` for the other.

Comment: Looking at what code?

Comment: The code that inspired this question. I can't post it

Comment: I see. I just saw the rest of your first comment - makes sense that it's not a good approach.

Comment: And we can't really offer useful suggestions for improving code that is not shown, except to make random guesses, nothing much more than a shot in the dark. My shot in the dark would be a `std::variant<std::map<std::string, Foo>, std::map<std::string, const Foo>>`, and then using `std::visit()` to dig inside it.

Comment: @EpicMochi referring to code not posted is poor form.

Comment: I can delete this question then.

Comment: you can just provide enough context (through code with similar requirements to your actual code) to make the question have sufficient context for it to be answered in a useful manner to you.

Answer (score 1):

A function that can accept both the const and non const versions of your map could be implemented in this manner:

```
template <typename T_foo>
T_foo do_something_with_map(std::map<std::string, T_foo> & map)
{
    std::cout << map["m"].i_ << std::endl;
    return map["m"];
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, const Foo> m1;
    Foo f1(1);
    m1.emplace("m", f1);

    std::map<std::string, Foo> m2;
    const Foo f2(2);
    m2.emplace("m", f2);

    auto res1 = do_something_with_map(m1);
    auto res2 = do_something_with_map(m2);
}
```

With an example Foo:

```
class Foo {
 public:
 Foo() = default;
 Foo(int i)
     : i_(i)
 {}
 int i_;
};
```

Comment: @xaxxon this seems like an attempted answer to me, but not worded well